# What is the correct way to query a column with IS NOT NULL with Prisma?

Tags: typescript, prisma

Is there a difference between these two queries?

```
this._client.myTable.findMany({
  where: {
    NOT: {
      myColumn: null
    }
  }
})
```

and

```
this._client.myTable.findMany({
  where: {
    myColumn: {
      not: null
    }
  }
})
```

or is there a more "correct" way to do this?

Comment: Should be the same. I'm guessing that they offer these two methods for readability (whichever way reads easier for you).

Answer (score 1):

Both queries you've mentioned are valid ways to query for records where `myColumn` is not `null` using Prisma, but they slightly differ in their approach:

1. Using `NOT` at the top level of the `where` clause:

   ```js
   this._client.myTable.findMany({
     where: {
       NOT: {
         myColumn: null
       }
     }
   })
   ```

   This approach specifies a condition where `myColumn` should not be `null` by using a `NOT` operator that negates the condition inside it.
2. Using `not` inside the condition for `myColumn`:

   ```js
   this._client.myTable.findMany({
     where: {
       myColumn: {
         not: null
       }
     }
   })
   ```

   This approach directly applies the `not` operator to `myColumn`, specifying that its value should not equal `null`.

**Which one is more "correct"?**

Both are correct and should yield the same result in this context. However, the choice between them can depend on readability or consistency with other parts of your codebase. The second approach (`myColumn: { not: null }`) is more direct and might be slightly more readable when dealing specifically with non-null conditions on a single column. It expresses the intent clearly and aligns with how you might handle other conditional operations in Prisma.

In summary, use the one that you find more readable and consistent with your project's coding standards. Both approaches are supported by Prisma and functionally equivalent for the purpose of excluding `null` values from the result set.